# Python cumulative and semester GPA calculator methods

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to write a method that calculates GPA. I want to calculate semester and cumulative. The code below is supposed to calculate the cumulative GPA (I have more options for other grades too). This is not producing values like 3.4, 3.5, as it should. And I am unsure how to calculate the semester grade using what I have. Any help is appreciated!

```
class GPA(object):
   def __init__(self, grade, hours):
    self.grade = grade
    self.hours = hours

def cumGPA(self, grade, hours):
    totPoint = 0
    totCred = 0

    if self.grade == 'A':
        totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours*4)
        totCred = float(totCred) +float(self.hours)

    if self.grade == 'B':
        totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours*3)
        totCred = float(totCred) +float(self.hours)

    if self.grade == 'C':
        totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours*2)
        totCred = float(totCred) +float(self.hours)

    if self.grade == 'D':
        totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours*1)
        totCred = float(totCred) +float(self.hours)

    else:
        totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours*0)
        totCred = float(totCred) +float(self.hours)

    return (totPoints / totCred)
```

I ran the following:

```
 test = GPA('A',12)
 test.cumGPA('A',12)
```

and I get 
     1010101.0

Comment: In Python 2.x dividing integer by integer returns an integer by default.

Comment: maybe you could show more detail of code,  because the  "totPoint " and "totCred" are not  defined at first, I'm not sure whether they are the global variation

Comment: @MichaelButscher should I wrap my values differently?

Comment: @bernieyum I'm so sorry, I forgot to rename above. I have fixed it.

Comment: Place a line `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of the module to switch to float division.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of code that fails? Including expected output and what is actually output. Regarding the division, the conversion to float that you're doing should be ok.

Comment: Maybe line 15 still have error, and you are better to show a complete code which includes init of class of GPA and some example args

Comment: @MichaelButscher the import statement did not work, but thank you.

Comment: @wjakobw I have added and updated.

Comment: @bernieyum I have added and updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Side note, the `grade` and `hours` params to the `cumGPA` function are unused.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I thought I was using them? Sorry, I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, at line 30 of your code, the "totPoints" maybe is a mistake.

secondly, the method of cumGPA doesn't use args of grade and hours.

Thirdly, you use if to dealing with many conditions.When the grade is A, first "if" will execute.But the code will continually run, and the GRADE is not equal "D", then the program will enter "Else condition"!

Maybe you could use "elif", like the code as following.

```
class GPA(object):
    def __init__(self, grade, hours):
        self.grade = grade
        self.hours = hours

    def cumGPA(self):
        totPoint = 0
        totCred = 0

        if self.grade == 'A':
            totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours * 4)
            totCred = float(totCred) + float(self.hours)

        elif self.grade == 'B':
            totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours * 3)
            totCred = float(totCred) + float(self.hours)

        elif self.grade == 'C':
            totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours * 2)
            totCred = float(totCred) + float(self.hours)

        elif self.grade == 'D':
            totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours * 1)
            totCred = float(totCred) + float(self.hours)

        else:
            totPoint = float(totPoint) + float(self.hours * 0)
            totCred = float(totCred) + float(self.hours)

        return (totPoint / totCred)


test = GPA('B', 0.3)
print test.cumGPA()
```

finally, from your code, the hour is irrelevant to result. The grade of A always is 4.0, B is 3.0 and so on. TotPoint and totCred equal zero at first, and A is just equal that **hours*4/hours**.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this to me, it really helps. From what you said, it appears my flaw is in the algorithm itself. Do you have any suggestions on how to adjust my code? I'm lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: How to calculate the GPA, I don't know your algorithm. Maybe you can provide it. At least, according to diff condition use 'elif' to cover.

Comment: My idea was to convert a letter grade to a point value, then multiply that by the number of credit hours the class is worth, then sum all the classes and divide by the total number of hours. I thought that is what  my code doing, but "hours" is not contributing.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some data and the rule about how to calculate the GPA. But how to design a  class Probably is another question.You can sent me a email